# La partición /boot está demasiado llena

Tags: linux, terminal, boot, archlinux

Mi problema es el siguiente estoy intentando instalar unos paquete en arch linux.

```
sudo pacman -S xf86-video-amdgpu amd-ucode
```

pero devuelve el siguiente error:

```
error: La partición /boot está demasiado llena: se necesitan 4956 bloques, hay 494 bloques libres
```

si ejecuto `df -h` recibo lo siguiente:

```
$ df -h                                     
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
dev              2,9G      0  2,9G   0% /dev
run              3,0G   1,1M  2,9G   1% /run
/dev/sda6         98G    19G   75G  21% /
tmpfs            3,0G    25M  2,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            3,0G    15M  2,9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1         96M    96M  494K 100% /boot
/dev/sda7        321G    53G  252G  18% /home
tmpfs            594M    72K  594M   1% /run/user/1000
```

tengo una computadora con dual boot una particion para windows y otra para linux.
Por lo que he invetigado el problema se puede resolver liberando espacio en /boot, es decir, eliminando kernels antiguos, pero no se como hacer esto en Arch.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda...

Comment: No puede con simplemente rm?

Comment: te refieres a remover /boot, tengo un dual boot, si hago esto voy a tener muchos problemas.

Comment: No, refiero a archivos vmlinux.* (y otros) de versiones antiguas que estén en /boot.

Comment: tienes razon. Pero como se cuales son?

Comment: Cuando instala un kernel nuevo, el programa de instalación no borra el previo.  Si hay un problema con el nuevo, se puede usar grub para boot la máquina con el prévio y rescatarse. Tengo una máquina con 4 archivos vmlinux y otra con 11. Con un linux Debian, puede usar apt-get para borrar la paja.  Arch usa pacman, no sé como hacerlo con pacman, será una manera.

Comment: Si ese es el problema, antes usaba ubuntu y se como hacer lo allí pero en ahora que uso arch no tengo ni idea

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la partición tiene muy poco espacio asignado (96 MB). Deberías darle más espacio, te recomiendo como mínimo 512 MB.
Para solucionar el problema temporalmente, te fijes que kernels tienes instalados, borres todos excepto el que estás usando actualmente.

Comment: Revisa [answer] y considera modificar tu respuesta, si bien es cierto que esta puede ser la solución no das más detalles sobre cómo lograrlo (es decir, qué comandos usar para tal fin sobre un sistema Arch Linux), aparte de que está información ya se le ha dado al OP en los comentarios.

Comment: como puedo ver los kernels que tengo, para elminarlos?